# Can I Use this fitting to connect CPVC tubing to a new shower valve

Tags: plumbing, shower, cpvc

I am replacing a 30+ year old shower valve as part of a master bath remodel.  The existing shower valve has 1/2" NPT female ports (qty 4), with one port capped.  The new valve has 1/2" NPT male connections (qty 3).  I have these fittings in my possession:

[image: 1/2 CPVC female to 1/2" NPT female fitting]

I'm just wondering if these are acceptable for this application.

A local big box store also (supposedly) has these fittings available:
[image]

which do not have the nut and gasket.  Are they both allowed? Is one better than the other?

I'm in Gwinnett County Georgia, USA.

Comment: You should not use a gasket for any joints which are inside a wall. NPT threads are tapered  and are tightened with a "permanent" sealing of pipe dope or Teflon tape. A gasket will eventually dry up, shrink, or deform and leak.   AFIK compression fittings are also allowed inside a wall as are various other new joining systems. Some local codes may prohibit certain joining systems which are allowed in other jurisdictions. Ask your local plumbing inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, both fittings are acceptable.  I ended up getting the second style, and after installation, there was a very small leak at the NPT thread.  I could not tighten it, since the CPVC does not rotate relative to the copper.  So, I had to cut the line tighten the fitting and then install a CPVC coupling.  Not a big deal, but had I installed the first type of fitting, I could have loosened the nut, tightened up the NPT joint and then tightened the nut.  Which I suspect is exactly the problem these fittings are meant to address.